# Ajax in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am using ajax in mvc for partial page refresh.

I create a partial view (ie a seperate user control) for each page and then call partial view by using Html.RenderPartial().

I just want to confirm that do I need to create a seperate user control for every page or is there any other way?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a separate user control for each logical unit that you want to partially render.  For more fine grained control, I will use javascript (jquery) to manipulate the DOM directly rather than rendering partials.

Comment: Agreed, it's better to use jquery (ASP.NET MVC is designed to have intellisense against jquery) to control the DOM than MS tools.  You have more granular control, this is exactly what I do. +1